# Opening Menu link in another tab

Tags: menus, links

I am adding a link to my Menu:

[image]

[image]

Everything is working correctly except I would like the link to open in another tab and can't figure out how to.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in the `Appearance > Menus` admin screen, click the `Screen Options` tab in the upper right corner, then under `Show advanced menu properties` tick the `Link Target` box. You'll now have a check box for each menu item labeled `Open link in a new window/tab`.

That said, many people these days do not take kindly to this sort of behavior. I think best practices are to let the end user decide how new links open via their own browser preferences.